# Resize multiple imageviews simultaneously

Tags: android, xml, imageview

I am making an app in which I have 12 `imageviews` over 3 rows and 4 columns. The problem I have is that with the

```
android: ScaleType = "fitXY"
```

I can only `autoscale` 4 last images that belong to the last row. What I need is for the 12 images automatically to resize because these 12 images are the same image simultaneously.

I know that with Java code it's possible, but my question is there something to `autoscale` XML or auto scale multiple `imageviews` to the same time.

Comment: You Should write a CustomImageview

Comment: I need something to do in XML file, not Java. thanks